# Having trouble with reversing an animation after unhovering

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in a bit of a pickle with this one. So I'm trying to reverse an animation after the element is unhovered (I have already the animation that when on hover plays and I just want to reverse it).

This is the keyframe

```
@keyframes appearbutton {
    0%{
        width:0px;
        height:0px;
    }
    50%{
        width:0px;
        height:30px;
    }
    100%{
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
    }
}
```

And using js I'm trying to check when I unhover the button using an eventlistener

```
window.load = Loaded();

function Loaded(){
    LoadImages();
    
    var searchitems = document.getElementById("siip");

    searchitems.addEventListener(onmouseleave, ReverseAnim());
}

function LoadImages(){ /// This works and is not a problem
    ...
}

function ReverseAnim(){
   console.log("Test");
}
```

But everytime the page loads the function is called and I see "Test" in console and when I unhover the button there isn't even a second "Test" appearing.

Also this is my HTML, I check whenever the mouse is over the "siip" element and not the input but the animation is on the inputs inside the CSS.

```
<div id="searchbar">
     <div class="searchitems" id="siip">
          <img src="images/searchbutton.png">
          <input type="text" class="textcassette" id="txtcass">
          <input type="sumbit" class="submitbutton" id="subbutt">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were calling the function directly, you have to pass reference of the function and also you have to use mouseleave instead of onmouseleave and it should be in quotes

```js
window.load = Loaded();

function Loaded(){
    LoadImages();
    
    var searchitems = document.getElementById("siip");

    searchitems.addEventListener('mouseleave', ReverseAnim);
}

function LoadImages(){ /// This works and is not a problem
    
}

function ReverseAnim(){
   console.log("Test");
}
```

```css
@keyframes appearbutton {
    0%{
        width:0px;
        height:0px;
    }
    50%{
        width:0px;
        height:30px;
    }
    100%{
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="searchbar">
     <div class="searchitems" id="siip">
          <img src="images/searchbutton.png">
          <input type="text" class="textcassette" id="txtcass">
          <input type="sumbit" class="submitbutton" id="subbutt">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, got home tried it out and worked. Thank you a lot, I tried 4 hours to solve this but didn't work only to find out this... Damn